# THREE.NURBSCurve getPoint(t)?

Tags: three.js

Ive tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas? 
I want to model along the NURBSCurve layout, can be seen from the fiddle to the layout of incremental model I used the 5 step, but in the use of getPoint method is obviously second position more than 5 cell model. Maybe I don't know the algorithm of getPoint. How can I get the point after the specified distance from the beginning of the curve? Thanks in advance.

```js
// Simple three.js example
var mesh, renderer, scene, camera, controls;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  // renderer
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  // scene
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // camera
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
  camera.position.set( 20, 20, 20 );

  // controls
  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );

  // ambient
  scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 ) );

  var size = 100;
  var divisions = 100;
  var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(size, divisions);
  scene.add(gridHelper);

  // light
  var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
  light.position.set( 20, 20, 0 );
  scene.add( light );

  // axes
  scene.add( new THREE.AxisHelper( 20 ) );

  var group = new THREE.Group();
            scene.add( group );

            // NURBS curve

            var nurbsControlPoints = [];
            var nurbsKnots = [];
            var nurbsDegree = 3;

            for ( var i = 0; i <= nurbsDegree; i ++ ) {

                nurbsKnots.push( 0 );

            }

            for ( var i = 0, j = 55; i < j; i ++ ) {

                nurbsControlPoints.push(
                    new THREE.Vector4(
                        i,
                        0,
                        0,
                        1 // weight of control point: higher means stronger attraction
                    )
                );

                var knot = ( i + 1 ) / ( j - nurbsDegree );
                nurbsKnots.push( THREE.Math.clamp( knot, 0, 1 ) );

            }

            var nurbsCurve = new THREE.NURBSCurve(nurbsDegree, nurbsKnots, nurbsControlPoints);

            var nurbsGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
            nurbsGeometry.vertices = nurbsCurve.getPoints(200);
            var nurbsMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { linewidth: 10, color: 0xffffff, transparent: true } );

            var nurbsLine = new THREE.Line( nurbsGeometry, nurbsMaterial );
            nurbsLine.position.set(0,0, 10 );
            group.add( nurbsLine );

      var current = nurbsCurve.getPoint(0), last = nurbsCurve.getPoint(1);
      var lineLength = current.distanceTo(last);
      var step=0;
      var length=0;
      for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
      {
          var pos= nurbsCurve.getPoint(step/lineLength);
          var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000}));
          pos.z=10;
          cube.position.copy(pos);
          scene.add(cube);
          step+=5;
      }
}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame( animate );

  //controls.update();

  renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/akmcv7Lh/132/`

Answer (score 0):

`THREE.NURBSCurve` derives from `THREE.Curve`, which implements a method named `getSpacedPoints`, which divides the curve in the given number of pieces of about equal
length and returns that many points plus one. Those points give the endpoints of each
piece of the curve. Example:

```
 var pieces=nurbsCurve.getSpacedPoints(5);
```

---

To get a point a specific distance from the curve, use:

```
 // If "distance" ranges from 0 to the curve's length, use:
 var point=nurbsCurve.getPointAt(distance/nurbsCurve.getLength());
 // If "distance" ranges from 0 to 1, use:
 var point=nurbsCurve.getPointAt(distance);
```

See [the three.js documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/extras/core/Curve) for more information on `THREE.Curve`.

---

Note also that I see a potential issue with your code:

```
 pos.z=10;
```

This gives the position of each cube point the same Z-coordinate. Your intent is probably
to shift the position of each cube by 10 instead. In that case, try this:

```
 pos.z+=10;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! My intention is not to divide the curve, but want to pass in a specific distance to get the coordinates of the specified length on the curve, use this point to locate my model. But I do not know if the realization, very much need your help, very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

getPoint expects a value between 0 and 1 included.
getPoint(0) will return the first point in the curve;
getPoint(0.5) will return the middle point in the curve;
getPoint(1) will return the last point in the curve.

In your example, you could have a value greater than 1, for example if the distance between the first and last point (=lineLength) is < 5, then on your second iteration, you already do 5/lineLength.

Instead of lineLength, you probably want to divide by 54, which is 55 minus 1.